# jqGrid data no longer appearing

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid, width

There are many threads regarding this very topic on this form; however, I still cannot get this to work correctly. I would like to set the width of the table to 900px. Furthermore, because I am displaying nearly a dozen rows, I would like for a scroll bar to be automatically implemented if the rows overflow the boundaries of the table size (if at all possible).

Problems I am currently experiencing:

1. User has help me to solve this issue, which was setting the width
2. Data is no longer appearing in my grid, guessing server-side issue.

**Updated to include full code:**

*HTML:*

```
      <?php 
require_once 'tabs.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery jqGrid Demonstration</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.multiselect.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // first create the grid
        $('#grid').jqGrid({
    url:'grid.php',
    datatype: "json",
    height: 100,
    width: 900,
    colNames:['Customer ID','Hardware ID', 'Username','Password','Email','Last Login','Last IP','Registration Date','Expire Date'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'customerid',index:'customerid', width:150, sorttype:'int'},
        {name:'hardware_id',index:'hardware_id', width:150},
        {name:'username',index:'username', width:100},
        {name:'password',index:'password', width:100},
        {name:'email',index:'email', width:100},
        {name:'lastlogin',index:'lastlogin', width:100},
        {name:'lastipaddress',index:'lastipaddress', width:100},
        {name:'registration_date',index:'registration_date', width:100},
        {name:'expire_date',index:'expire_date', width:100}
    ],
    rowNum:5,
    rowList:[5,8,10,20,30], 
    mtype: "GET",
    gridview: true,
    pager: '#pager',
    sortname: 'customerid',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "Virtual scrolling on local data"
});

$("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager', {view: true,del:false});
        // now you can any time change the width of the grid
        $('#grid').jqGrid('setGridWidth', 900);


    });

//]]>
</script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div>
          <?php include ("grid.php");?>
      </div>
      <div id="pager"></div>

   </body>
</html>
```

*SEVER-SIDE (grid.php)*

```
<?php

include '../dbc.php';
page_protect();
require_once 'jq-config.php';
// include the jqGrid Class
require_once ABSPATH."php/jqGrid.php";
// include the driver class
require_once ABSPATH."php/jqGridPdo.php";
// Connection to the server

$link = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
// Tell the db that we use utf-8
$link ->query("SET NAMES utf8");

// Create the jqGrid instance
$grid = new jqGridRender($link);

$username = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$grid->SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblcustomer_$username";
// set the ouput format to json
$grid->dataType = 'json';
// Let the grid create the model
$grid->setColModel();
// Set the url from where we obtain the data
$grid->setUrl('grid.php');
// Set some grid options
$grid->setGridOptions(array("rowNum"=>100,"sortname"=>"customerid","height"=>150));

// Change some property of the field(s)
$grid->setColProperty("lastlogin", array(
    "formatter"=>"date",
    "formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-m-d H:i:s","newformat"=>"m/d/Y"),
    "search"=>false,
    "width"=>"400"
    ));
// Registration date
$grid->setColProperty("registration_date", array(
    "formatter"=>"date",
    "formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-m-d H:i:s","newformat"=>"m/d/Y"),
    "search"=>false,
    "width"=>"400"
    ));
$grid->setColProperty("expire_date", array(
    "formatter"=>"date",
    "formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-m-d H:i:s","newformat"=>"m/d/Y"),
    "search"=>false,
    "width"=>"400"
    ));
$grid->setColProperty("customerid",array("width"=>"650"));
$grid->setColProperty("hardware_id",array("width"=>"250"));
$grid->setColProperty("username",array("width"=>"150"));
$grid->setColProperty("password",array("width"=>"150"));
$grid->setColProperty("email",array("width"=>"150"));
$grid->setColProperty("lastipaddress",array("width"=>"100"));

$grid->setFilterOptions(array("stringResult"=>true));
$grid->navigator=true;
$grid->setNavOptions('navigator',array("excel"=>true,"add"=>true,"edit"=>true,"view"=>true,"del"=>true,"search"=>true));
// Enjoy
$grid->renderGrid('#grid','#pager',true, null, null, true,true);
$link = null;
?>
```

I feel as though I have tried everything, but if anyone sees what I cannot, please feel free to let me know!

Thank you for the help,

Evan

Comment: Have you double checked the size of the parent element?

Comment: Yes, I am able to use the following event to change the grid's width (only works when the screen is re-sized though).


$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    $("#grid").setGridWidth($(window).width());
}).trigger('resize');

Comment: First you should insert in you JavaScript code `);` at the end of code which will correspond to `$(document).ready(function() {`. Currently you have syntax error in the code. Second `sortname: 'item_id'` is wrong because the grid has no column `'item_id'`.

Comment: @Oleg - I thought i had updated it correctly, it's not there in the current version (will fix now). Also, I updated the issue that I am having as you solved one part of it, which in turn caused another issue. Guessing this error is server-side related?

Comment: jqGrid is open source *JavaScript* code. In your question you posted PHP code. Moreover it uses *commercial* product from  http://www.trirand.net/. I personally don't use PHP and of course not use jqGrid for PHP. If you would catch the JSON results which return your server code `'grid.php'` (you can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to catch HTTP traffic) one could analyse the problem independent on the PHP code.

Comment: @Oleg I'm sorry but I've been TERRIBLY lost over the last couple of days with this very frustrating plugin. One thing will work, and another wont; the next moment the two switch and I'm stuck all over again. I truly need someone to take a close look at my code and see where it is not linking.

Comment: I want help you, but I can't help you in PHP or jqGrid for PHP or *commercial* product from [trirand.net](http://www.trirand.net/). You can post your question in the [jqSuite forums](http://www.trirand.net/forum/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no `gridComplete` method of `jQuery(document)`. You mean sure `jQuery.ready`. Moreover you can use `setGridWidth` on `<table id="grid">` only after you convert if to grid. Moreover the code `$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = false;` and `$.jgrid.useJSON = true;` should be executed before `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and after `grid.locale-en.js`. So the code should be about the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = false;
    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // first create the grid
        $('#grid').jqGrid({
            // parameters of jqGrid
        }); 

        // now you can any time change the width of the grid
        $('#grid').jqGrid('setGridWidth', 900);
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Updated to show full code and further explained issue. Thank you!

Comment: @Evan: I received voting down probably because my answer is on your **original** question and not on the last version of the question. So, please, always just *append* the text of your question with words like "**UPDATED:**" which follows new version of your code.

Comment: I will just have to post a new question then with appropriate guidelines. I didn't realize the harm I was causing, terribly sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your jqgrid initialization code?  Here's an example I have that should do what you describe:

```
$("#Building_8839_Transactions").jqGrid({

"colModel":[{"editable":false,"name":"TRANS_YEAR","label":"Year","width":"100.0"},{"name":"TRANS_DESCRIP","editable":true,"editrules":{"required":false},"label":"Action","width":"300.0"},{"name":"BLS_ID","hidden":true,"key":true}],

"shrinkToFit":false,
"sortorder":"desc",
"height":"auto",
"jsonReader":{"page":"PAGE","records":"RECORDS","repeatitems":false,"total":"TOTAL","root":"ROWS"},
"width":"500",
"viewrecords":true,
"editurl":"foobar.cfm",
"datatype":"json",
"caption":"BLS Transactions",
"rowNum":"15",
"url":"blah.cfm",
"sortname":"TRANS_YEAR"         
});
```

The important bits are the "width": "500", and "shrinkToFit":false.  Try those.

Comment: Just curious, what is the difference between editurl and url?

Comment: editurl is the url that handles inserts/updates/deletes, and url is the url that handles reads (including paging/sorting/filtering)

Comment: Am I doing something completely wrong in my server side code if the records aren't even coming in? They were prior to making the front-end changes this thread suggested i make, however.

Comment: See if you are getting an error, either at the JS level or as part of the response from the server.  Also, you could possibly be getting back data that doesn't match the format you specified in your grid definition, so check that too.

Comment: I'm trying not to sound moronic here, but I do not recall, nor do I see anywhere that I defined a data format. Where are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this by PHP:

```
// Set table with auto
$grid->setGridOptions(array( 
    "rowNum"=>10, 
    "sortable"=>true, 
    "rownumbers"=>true,
    "width"=>'auto',
    "altRows"=>true, 
    "multiselect"=>true, 
    "rowList"=>array(10,20,50), 
    )); 

// Set table with 100px
$grid->setGridOptions(array( 
    "rowNum"=>10, 
    "sortable"=>true, 
    "rownumbers"=>true,
    "width"=>1000,
    "altRows"=>true, 
    "multiselect"=>true, 
    "rowList"=>array(10,20,50), 
    ));
```

[Check my complete code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399655/increase-the-width-of-jqgrid-table/15408813#15408813)