# increase the width of jqgrid table

Tags: php, json, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I am new in jqgrid and I would like to increase the width of jqgrid.
I have increased the column width but the grid width is not increasing. 
I am using php jqgrid.

Is there any parameters to pass this function :=

```
$grid->renderGrid('#grid','#pager',true, null, null, true,true);
```

or How can i do this ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You question is mostly about the commercial version of jqGrid, which I don't know. The main problem exist also in the jqGrid too. jqGrid has [width](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) parameter which can be used to define the grid width. I suppose that you should use (or already use) `$grid->setGridOptions` to define the option. Another option which can be additionally used are `autowidth` which will be overwrite the `width` value calculated based on the size of the grid's parent. Other important option can be important you: `shrinkToFit` which default value is `true`. It meant that the `width` properties for the column will be not used as the exact column width in pixel. Instead of that the `width` properties will be used to define only *proportion* between the column widths. If the column width of some column should be not changed you should include `fixed: true` property in the `colModel` for the corresponding definition of the column. If you want to have *exact column width* for all columns (as it's defined in `width` properties of the items of the `colModel`) you should use the jqGrid setting `shrinkToFit: false`. Try to include the setting in the `$grid->setGridOptions` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below php code:

```
// Set grid with 1000px by php
$grid->setGridOptions(array("width"=>1000));
```

I had same issue, my grid was taking 650px by default with. So, I check some blog and also [wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) and now is ended up with :)

Here is my complete php code with auto grid width:

```
<?php
require_once '../../../jq-config.php';
// include the jqGrid Class
require_once ABSPATH."php/jqGrid.php";
// include the driver class
require_once ABSPATH."php/jqGridPdo.php";
// Connection to the server
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
// Tell the db that we use utf-8
$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");

// Create the jqGrid instance
$grid = new jqGridRender($conn);
// SQL query
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT *,
CASE total_correct_answer 
WHEN total_correct_answer=1 THEN 1
WHEN total_correct_answer=2 THEN 3 
ELSE 6 
END AS points
FROM 
(
SELECT COUNT(*) total_correct_answer, v.coupon_code_id, v.coupon_no, v.login_id, v.cc_match_id, v.name, v.contact_no, v.email, v.user_from
FROM (
SELECT p.login_id, ui.name, ui.contact_no,l.email,l.user_from,
p.quiz_id p_quiz_id,p.question_bank_id p_question_bank_id, p.answer_id p_answer_id, 
cc.quiz_id cc_quiz_id,cc.question_bank_id cc_question_bank_id, cc.answer_id cc_answer_id, 
cc.match_id cc_match_id, p.coupon_code_id, cd.coupon_no  
FROM prediction p
INNER JOIN correct_answer cc 
INNER JOIN `user_information` ui ON p.`login_id` = ui.`login_id` 
INNER JOIN coupon_code cd ON cd.coupon_code_id = p.coupon_code_id
INNER JOIN login l ON l.login_id = p.login_id
WHERE cc.quiz_id=p.quiz_id AND cc.question_bank_id=p.question_bank_id 
AND cc.answer_id=p.answer_id AND cc.match_id IN (SELECT match_id FROM `match` WHERE 
start_time BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW())
) v GROUP BY v.coupon_code_id ORDER BY v.login_id DESC 
) a 
SQL;
// Write the SQL Query
$grid->SelectCommand = $sql;
// Set output format to json
$grid->dataType = 'json';
// Let the grid create the model
$grid->setColModel();
// Set the url from where we obtain the data
$grid->setUrl('grid.php');
// Set alternate background using altRows property
$grid->setGridOptions(array( 
    "rowNum"=>10, 
    "sortable"=>true, 
    "rownumbers"=>true,
    "width"=>'auto',
    "altRows"=>true, 
    "multiselect"=>true, 
    "rowList"=>array(10,20,50), 
    )); 
// Change some property of the field(s) 
$grid->setColProperty("total_correct_answer", array("label"=>"Answer", "width"=>80));
$grid->setColProperty("coupon_code_id", array("label"=>"Coupon Code", "width"=>80));
$grid->setColProperty("coupon_no", array("label"=>"Coupon Number", "width"=>120));
$grid->setColProperty("login_id", array("label"=>"User ID", "width"=>80));
$grid->setColProperty("cc_match_id", array("label"=>"Match ID", "width"=>80));
$grid->setColProperty("name", array("label"=>"User Name", "width"=>120));
$grid->setColProperty("contact_no", array("label"=>"Contact No", "width"=>120));
$grid->setColProperty("email", array("label"=>"User Email", "width"=>120));
$grid->setColProperty("user_from", array("label"=>"User Mode", "width"=>120));
$grid->setColProperty("points", array("label"=>"User Points", "width"=>120));
// Enable navigator
$grid->navigator = true;
// Enable excel export
$grid->setNavOptions('navigator', array("excel"=>true,"add"=>false,"edit"=>false,"del"=>false,"view"=>false));
// Set different filename 
$grid->exportfile = 'Prediction_Report.xls'; 
// Enjoy
$grid->renderGrid('#grid','#pager',true, null, null, true,true);
$conn = null;
?>
```